# Replacing all occurrences of '1000' within HTML element in Javascript

Tags: javascript, replace

I'm currently trying to replace the occurrences of the number 999 in the HTML as shown below. I have added the third line, which is breaking the script.

```
var new_id = uniqid(),
    new_field_html = repeater.find('> table > tbody > tr.row-clone').html()
                .replace(/(=["]*[\w-\[\]]*?)(\[999\])/g, '$1[' + new_id + ']');
    new_field_html = new_field_html.('div.checkbox_container').html()
                .replace('1000', new_id);
    new_field = $('<tr class="row"></tr>').append( new_field_html );
```

The variable 1000 which I am trying to replace occurs in a number of places, such as ID of `<li>` elements and `onclick` Javascript elements.

### Final solution

The code above has now been changed as follows:

```
var new_id = uniqid();
var new_field_html = repeater.find('> table > tbody > tr.row-clone')
                     .html().replace(/(=["]*[\w-\[\]]*?)(\[999\])/g, 
                     '$1[' + new_id + ']').replace(/1000/g, new_id)
                     .replace(/999/g, new_id);
new_field = $('<tr class="row"></tr>').append( new_field_html );
```

Comment: `Type issue - 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'new_field_html.html()')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new_html_field variable is not a jQuery object, you can't use jQuery methods on it. You can make it a jquery object by doing `$(new_field_html)`.

A second problem is in this bit:

```
new_field_html.('div.checkbox_container')
```

You probably meant to use

```
new_field_html.find('div.checkbox_container')
```

Putting it together:

```
new_field_html = $(new_field_html)
                     .find('div.checkbox_container')
                     .html().replace('1000', new_id);
```

Comment: So should it be as follows? 

`new_field_html = $(new_field_html).('div.checkbox_container').html().replace('1000', new_id);`

Comment: You're still missing the `find`. Check my last example.

Comment: By the way, this is assuming that new_html_field indeed contains a div with class checkbox_container.

Comment: Getting close thanks! Unfortunately, it's currently just replacing all of the HTML with `new_id`, rather than occurrences of 1000. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle? Then I'll take a look